# Get all the form input fields from a Page

Tags: html, ajax

So basically, I have a lot of form fields (About 50 or so). Doing an AJAX request is going to be astronomically big, and it will most likely just make my code look ugly and unreadable. Is there anyway to gather all form data from a page and do an AJAX request?

Answer (score 1):

If you had the names of the object for each input box like:

```
<input type="text" data-ajax="MyAjaxObjectName1" />
```

You could recurse through all of the inputs in this way:

```
var ajaxObject = {};
$('#myContainer input[type=text]').each(function() {
    var inputObject = $(this).data('MyAjaxObjectName1')
    ajaxObject[inputObject] = $(this).val()
}
```

That is the simplest way I can think of to recurse through every field that you have. Although, you'd have to update the HTML to include those attributes

Answer (score 0):

The jQuery 'serialize' method:

> **Description:** Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.

See https://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `$.serializeArray()` on the form element.

It returns an array with each name and value of form inputs.

Docu & examples: https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/